# Quadratic residue of $-1$ in composite modulus

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

It is true for each odd prime number p that if $x^2\equiv-1 \pmod p$ then $p\equiv1\pmod 4$

I've observed that it should be true for all composite integers, whose prime factors are congruent to $1$ modulo $4$. However I couldn't find any remark on the internet whether it's true.

In other words, if it is correct, how do we prove that $x^2\equiv-1\pmod n$ has a solution if and  only if $n=\prod_{p|n}p$ such that $p_i=4k_i+1$

P.S: My level is pretty elementary.

Comment: If $x^2 \equiv a \pmod{n}$, then also $x^2\equiv a \pmod{p}$ for all primes dividing $n$. Note that you have to allow one factor $2$ or restrict to odd $n$, as for example $3^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{10}$.

Comment: This implies if $x^2\equiv -1\pmod n$ has a solution, then all of the prime factors must be congruent to $1$. But does it imply the reverse?

Comment: I guess I should've said "if and only if", let me edit that.

Answer (score 3):

For an odd $n$, there are $x$ with $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$ if and only if all prime divisors of $n$ are of the form $p = 4m+1$.

The necessity follows from $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{n} \Rightarrow x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{d}$ for all divisors $d$ of $n$, in particular its prime divisors.

The sufficiency follows from the Chinese Remainder Theorem, and the fact that for any prime $p$ and $k \geqslant 1$ the group of units in $\mathbb{Z}/(p^k)$ is cyclic.

Since the group is cyclic and its order is a multiple of $4$ for $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, it contains elements of order $4$, and these satisfy $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{p^k}$ (since $$x^4-1 = (x^2-1)(x^2+1) = (x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^k},$$ and neither $x-1$ nor $x+1$ can be divisible by $p$).

Once you have solutions $x_i$ modulo each prime power $p_i^{k_i}$ dividing $n$, the Chinese Remainder Theorem asserts the existence of $x$ with

$$x \equiv x_i \pmod{p_i^{k_i}},\quad 1\leqslant i \leqslant r,$$

where $n = \prod\limits_{i=1}^r p_i^{k_i}$, and such an $x$ satisfies $x^2 \equiv -1\pmod{n}$. Since for each prime power $p_i^{k_i}$ there are exactly $2$ solutions, there are $2^r$ solutions of $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{n}$.

Comment: To emphasize the first statement, we can find a counterexample by picking a product of primes that is $1 \bmod 4$, but includes at least one prime that is $3 \bmod 4$. The simplest is a product of two primes that are $3 \bmod 4$: e.g. $21 = 3 \cdot 7$.

Comment: Nice (+1). I think you should also discuss the case where $n$ is even.

Comment: @quasi the even moduli are just those twice the appropriate odd ones. I wrote a short answer proving this.

Answer (score 1):

To draw a distinction: for any (positive) prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ there is always a solution in integers to
$$  x^2 - p y^2 = -1.   $$ There is a short proof in Mordell's book, Diophantine equations.

As Daniel has shown, $-1$ remains a quadratic residue for the product of such primes. However, sometimes the "negative Pell equation" has roots then, sometimes not. There is no solution in integers to 
$$  x^2 - 205 y^2 = -1   $$ or
$$   x^2 - 221 y^2 = -1.   $$
Go Figure.

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell
Input n for Pell 
205

0  form   1 28 -9   delta  -3
1  form   -9 26 4   delta  6
2  form   4 22 -21   delta  -1
3  form   -21 20 5   delta  4
4  form   5 20 -21   delta  -1
5  form   -21 22 4   delta  6
6  form   4 26 -9   delta  -3
7  form   -9 28 1   delta  28
8  form   1 28 -9

 disc   820


 Pell automorph 
39689  568260
2772  39689

Pell unit 
39689^2 - 205 * 2772^2 = 1 

========================================= 

jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell
Input n for Pell 
221

0  form   1 28 -25   delta  -1
1  form   -25 22 4   delta  6
2  form   4 26 -13   delta  -2
3  form   -13 26 4   delta  6
4  form   4 22 -25   delta  -1
5  form   -25 28 1   delta  28
6  form   1 28 -25

 disc   884



 Pell automorph 
1665  24752
 112  1665

Pell unit 
1665^2 - 221 * 112^2 = 1 

=========================================
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Comment: We can assess the existence of a negative Pell solution from the continued fraction for $\sqrt{n}$. Iff the cycle this generates is of odd length, you're good. This can occur only when $n$ has only $4k+1$ prime factors plus at most one power of $2$, but those conditions are not sufficient to always have an odd-length cycle. For example, $34$ has a suitable prime factorization $2×17$, but the continued fraction of its square root is $[5,\overline{1,4,1,10}]$.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Fischer has explained thst for odd $n$ all prime factors must be $\equiv1\bmod4$. We could equivalently require all factors, prime or otherwise, of an odd $n$ to have this residue.

If $n$ is even render it as $2^km$ for odd $m$ and $k$ a positive whole number. Then $-1$ will be a quadratic residue $\bmod n$ iff it is so both $\bmod 2^k$ and $\bmod m$. Thus $m$ has to satisfy the criteria noted by Daniel Fischer, while for $\bmod 2^k$ we have $1^2\equiv-1$ when $k=1$. But no square root of $-1$ exists for any $k\ge 2$; there are simply no squares one less than a multiple of $4$ which such a root would imply.

So the even moduli for which $-1$ is a quadratic residue are just those twice the appropriate odd ones. Thus if $-1$ is a quadratic residue $\bmod 5$ it will be so $\bmod 10$, $\bmod 13$ similarly implies $\bmod 26$, etc.

Comment: Thanks for resolving the case where $n$ is even.